# Filtering cells to concatenate based on their contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with some `.CSV` files that basically contain a list of transcribed comments and timestamps, and I wish to use VB to concatenate some of them. I've generated a script which sort of does this 'the long way round' by recording macros, googling and searching stack overflow, however it takes a while to run and uses a rather silly process.

What my script is doing is basically concatenating 1500 entries in columns E and F into some empty cells, doing a find and replace to replace empty timestamps with nothing (and to remove unnecessary leading zeros), copying everything back, and then running a search and removing the last 7 characters (i.e. the timestamp.. assuming there are no hours!) when a few specific trigger words are found. The idea being that I want most of the range to concat, but not in cases where cells contain certain trigger words.

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, Cel As Range

'Concatenates Comments and timestamps into BA1

        Range("BA1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCAT(RC[-48],"" ("",TEXT(RC[-47],""hh:mm:ss""),"")"")"
        Range("BA1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("BA1:BA1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("BA1:BA1500").Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Apply timestamp corrections

        Selection.Replace What:="(00:00:00)", Replacement:=""
        Selection.Replace What:="(00:", Replacement:="("

'Copy column BA1 back into data, then empty

        Range("BA1:BA1500").Copy
        Columns("E:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Columns("BA:BA").ClearContents

'Remove timestamps when certain words are found

        Set SrchRng = Range("E1:E1500")

            For Each Cel In SrchRng
                If InStr(1, Cel.Value, "APPLE") > 0 Or _
                    InStr(1, Cel.Value, "ORANGE") > 0 Or _
                    InStr(1, Cel.Value, "BANANA") > 0 Or _
                    InStr(1, Cel.Value, "MANGO") > 0 Then
                    Cel = Left(Cel, Len(Cel) - 7)
                End If
            Next Cel
```

I imagine a better way to do this would be to filter and only concat the appropriate cells in the first place, rather than concatenating all and then searching through through them to delete things (which is also not very robust, as timestamps longer than an hour have more than 7 characters anyway).

Is this 'filtered concat' possible and does this make sense? I'm not sure where to start with this as I'm very much a newbie (and not much of a logical thinker either apparently!)

Any pointers very much appreciated!

[image: Desired Output]

The rows with uppercase trigger words APPLE, ORANGE and BANANA would not have been concatenated, and so do not have a timestamp at the end. The rows with the word SCORE in column D would ideally also not be concatenated, but that's less of a priority!

Comment: Would you be able to post a screenshot of your desired goal?

Comment: Kubie- thanks for your response and sorry I didn't see it sooner. I've just updated the post with a screenshot as requested.